# Using 4 inch tube for 3 inch wheel

Tags: innertube, electric-bike

fellow bicyclists.

I purchased an e-bike (Clou Tumbler) and its back wheel is 20x3.0
I overpumped air into it and the tube blew up, so I've been trying to find a replacement, only to realize its apparently nearly impossible to find anything of this size in Finland.

The best next thing I found is sized 20x4.0 (https://www.puuilo.fi/chaoyang-polkupyoran-sisarengas-20-fat-bike-100-120-406) and I am wondering if this could work at all?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your question is really about a combination of frame clearance (will the extra wide tyre fit through the frame without rub) AND whether it will mount safely on the existing rim.

Comment: @Criggie I think this is about the inner tube (the product link is for a 20" wheel, 4-4.9" width) Ordinarily I'd think a slightly bigger inner tube (eg for up to 32 mm vs for up to 28 mm) would be fine, but at fat bike tire sizes, I don't know. Never seen these up close.

Comment: @sergei could you please confirm Tube or Tyre?  Title says tube, but question text says tyre, and link is to a tube.

Comment: @Criggie sorry, somehow did not receive a notification... and thank you for replying. 

yes, indeed, it is a tube - apologies for the confusion. tire itself is ok, it is the inner tube that got blown up. i still have not found anything of sorts in Finland.

Comment: @newroadie thank you for the reply! yes, 4 mm difference would probably have been ok, here it is a whopping extra 2.5cm difference, but then again - fatbike, so maybe some wiggle room is possible? it is 25% difference, versus 14% difference in your example (32mm vs 28mm). also possible that i will just have to buy and try it

Answer (score 2):

I've found that a smaller tube than the tire - say using a 20x2.5 or 20x2.75 inch tube in a 3 inch tire works.

But, using a larger tube than the tire can be problematic. In your case the tube is a whole inch bigger. This means that you will have to stuff the tube into the tire - and you can probably do it - that will cause folds in the tube that will rub against each other inside the tire. This will cause wear and eventually a hole that leaks air.

Your experience might be better. Let us know how it turns out in the long run and if you did something to make it work.